Optimizing Batch Greenscreen Keying with FFmpeg
Optimizing Batch Greenscreen Keying with FFmpeg
Hi all!
I’ve written a script that batch processes MP4 videos with a variable greenscreen color code, replacing the background with a video. While it works well overall, I’m not fully satisfied with the results yet.
Issues I’m facing:
A slight green halo still present around the subject.
Blurry edges, especially between the arms. This results from the boxblur, which i needed to adjust to get rid of excess green coloring
Here is the FFmpeg command I’m using:
ffmpeg -y -i "%background%" -i "%input_file%" -filter_complex "[1:v]chromakey=%color_code%:similarity=0.28:blend=0.01[ckout];[ckout]split[ck1][ck2];[ck1]alphaextract[alph];[alph]boxblur=2:1[alph_processed];[ck2][alph_processed]alphamerge[ck_blurred];[0:v][ck_blurred]overlay[out]" -map "[out]" -map 1:a -c:v !video_codec! !video_encoding_options! -c:a !audio_codec! "!output_file!"
I fidgetet a little bit to find the "OK"-working settings in Similarity, blend and boxblur.
I’m looking for suggestions on how to optimize this FFmpeg code or apply alternative filters to improve these issues. I’ve attached a sample video for reference.
Pictures for reference:
with Background
[With Greenscreen2
Videos for download as reference:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-9uHErLAo2aniv0N7uvMDreweuoz-RSQ?usp=sharing

Apply https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#despill right after the chromakey. (Also no need to split and merge alpha, boxblur can work on just the alpha channel)

Thank you so much, I will try it asap!
